# Why can't I have static public fields in my managed beans?

Tags: netbeans, jsf-2, cdi, netbeans-7

I just started using the Netbeans 7.1 beta and it is calling out errors of a type which I have never seen before.  Specifically:

`A managed bean with a public field should not declare any scope other than @Dependent.`

The fields it is complaining about are `public static final`.  I can understand the restriction on non-static fields, but I can't think of a good reason this would not be allowed for a static field.   Unfortunately I use a lot of them since I don't like having constants in my code.

I note that even though I get the red dot in the margin in the editor, the maven-driven build still works and GlassFish still runs my application the way I would expect.

So what is my denoument on this issue?  Am I going to have to move my static fields elsewhere or is there another way of handling this?

Comment: Note: JSF doesn't forbid that. It's Netbeans who does that for some unclear reason, perhaps by some CDI spec restriction. As it's apparently a beta version, I'd just report a bug to the Netbeans guys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting the `javax.enterprise.inject` [package javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/inject/package-summary.html):

> If a managed bean has a public field, it must have scope @Dependent.

But I do agree wih @BalusC that if this compiles, Netbeans should report it as Warning (does it?).

Anyway, are those constants really part of the API? I mean, do you access they anywhere else but within their own classes? If not, reduce visibility to private. (If you just need to access the constants from the view you can also create accessors for the private constant). If yes, I would suggest you to move them somewhere else anyway.

Comment: NetBeans 7.1 beta (not prior versions) mark the class line with a red dot in the left margin.  However that error does not extend to the projects window the way other errors do.  You are right that many of my constants can be designated private instead of public, and I could refactor exportable constants to getters (not setters!).  This took me by surprise, though.  Most JSF requirements make intuitive sense when you examine them; this one still doesn't.

Comment: Fixed the mutator part for further reference, bad case of tired developer high on coffee after midnight hehehe. Anyway, if you wish to report a bug for the Netbeans team, [here](http://netbeans.org/community/issues.html)'s the place. If it compiles and runs fine, maybe the Netbeans team misinterpreted the [specs](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr299/index.html) (or maybe the specs aren't clear about static variables, and it is left as a implementation specific detail...). Just in case, read the specs and be prepared for a open edge debate it it follows down that road.

Comment: Here's the quote from the linked specs: (Page 27, - 3.1 Managed Beans): 

`If a managed bean with a public field declares any
scope other than @Dependent, the container automatically detects the problem and treats it as a definition error.`

It says nothing about class variables vs object fields, but maybe this is a good question for Gavin King :D.

Comment: Can the visibility be protected? Also, why can't a field be public? This makes using legacy code a pain. Really.

Answer (score 4):

Public fields (static or not) aren't proxyable - that's why they can only be dependent scoped. To work around this you obviously can access them through getter methods.